# Django: Update multiple rows with value from relation

Tags: django, django-queryset

We have thousands of rows in our DB that all needs a database migration applied.
We have so many rows that spans goes back 8 years, and it's not really feasible for us to run `save()` on each individual instance, as in this example here:

```
update_list = OrderProduct.objects.filter(
    product__isnull=False,
    title="unnamed")

for op in update_list:
    op.title = op.product.title
    op.save()  # We would prefer a update() query rather than individual saves
```

So we are trying to do this with a db query. I'm aware that `F()` doesn't support joins when using it inside `update()`, which is why I was trying to be smart with the following:

```
OrderProduct.objects\
    .filter(title="unnamed", product__isnull=False)\
    .annotate(copy_title=F('product__title'))\
    .update(title=F('copy_title'))
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work, so I'm wondering if there is a simple way to achieve this with a django update(), rather than cycling through every row.

Comment: Have you tried bulk_update? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Comment: @KJTHoward somehow I missed the existence of that method O.O ... thx I'll have a peek at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imports:

```
from django.db import transaction
from bulk_update.helper import bulk_update
```

You need to put your rows to a list which is param of functions create_objects & update_objects

You can try bulk_create:

```
    def create_objects(create_objects: list, chunk_size=2000):
    if len(create_objects):
        with transaction.atomic():
            model_cls: Model = create_objects[0].__class__
            for chunk_list in ModelHelpers.chunk_iterate(create_objects, chunk_size):
                model_cls.objects.bulk_create(chunk_list)

    return create_objects
```

and bulk_update:

```
    @staticmethod
    def update_objects(update_objects: list, update_fields=None, chunk_size=2000):
    if update_objects:
        with transaction.atomic():
            for chunk_list in ModelHelpers.chunk_iterate(update_objects, chunk_size):
                bulk_update(chunk_list, update_fields=update_fields)
```

You need chunk_iterate function for them:

```
    @staticmethod
    def chunk_iterate(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Can't be sure what `bulk_update.helper` is because you haven't included any info on it but since Django 2.2 `bulk_update()` is a queryset method. Also, the `bulk_create()` and `bulk_update()` methods can take an optional parameter called `batch_size` so chunking like this is unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm, missed the bulk_update() method somehow. Will give that a go.

Comment: Just an update. I did actually end up chunking the updates, as well as using the batch_size param for the bulk update. This was to save on memory when updating each of the rows.